# How to write a file to Google Cloud Storage using Deployment Manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-deployment-manager

I see in the list of [Supported Resource Types](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) that Google Cloud Deployment Manager has at least some support for the `storage.v1.object` type. I'm hoping this gives me the ability to write files to GCS based on data in my DM template. I'm stuck, though, on how to even compose the properties for the resource in a way that DM likes. When I use the following template:

```
resources:
  - name: foo.txt
    type: storage.v1.object
    properties:
      bucket: my-bucket
      name: foo.txt
      uploadType: media
```

I get the following error from `gcloud deployment-manager`:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1522258413242-5687c67fa4691-c89f17c6-c0b96018]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/test-serviceaccount/resources/foo.txt
  message: '{"ResourceType":"storage.v1.object","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Upload
    requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with
    /upload/","reason":"wrongUrlForUpload","extendedHelp":"https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload"}],"message":"Upload
    requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with
    /upload/","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

What am I missing here? How do I construct a valid `storage.v1.object` resource in a Deployment Manager template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this Github thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues/40):

> "uploading objects to Cloud Storage isn't really a supported use case"
>   in Deployment Manager.

However, the proposed workarounds in the thread to upload an object from Deployment Manager are:

- Create a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) and call it from the Deployment Manager with:

  `action: gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1beta2:cloudfunctions.projects.locations.functions.call`

  You can find a Cloud Functions example in the [deploymentmanager-samples repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/cloud_functions).
- Use [Google Cloud Container Builder](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/).

You can use the following example as a reference for Cloud Builder. It clones a repository (you can use your own image instead and [run a custom script](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/create-custom-build-steps)) and uploads the directory to a bucket.

```
resources:
  - name: my-build
    action: gcp-types/cloudbuild-v1:cloudbuild.projects.builds.create
    metadata:
      runtimePolicy:
      - CREATE
    properties:
      steps:
      - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
        args: ['clone', 'https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-helloworld-php.git']
      - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
        args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', 'appengine-helloworld-php', 'gs://<MY_BUCKET>/']
      timeout: 120s
```